# phonegap .load jQuery doesn't load

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [phonegap form submission to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962527/phonegap-form-submission-to-remote-server)

Another question. If this one can be solved, I'll definitely can solve this one [phonegap form submission to remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7962527/phonegap-form-submission-to-remote-server).

So here's the code
**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
<link href="jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="jquery.mobile.scrollview.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="index.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>    
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0rc1.min.js"></script>
<script src="phonegap-1.0.0.js"></script>

<script>
function onLoad()
{
    $('#content').load('http://xxx.com/xxx/get.php');

}
</script>

</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="header">

<div data-role="header">
<h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div data-role="content" id="content">
<input type="button" value="click" onClick="onLoad();">
</div>

<div data-role="footer" id="footer">
<h4>Footer</h4>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

**get.php**

```
<?php
echo '<p>this is a test</p>';
?>
```

A very simple code, but it doesn't work. Can someone point out where did I do wrong? What I want to do is to get the response from **get.php**(remote server). So it would print "*this is a test*" from **get.php** into **#content div** in **index.html**. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your onLoad function is only called when you click on your input (as jensgram pointed out):

```
<script>
function onLoad()
{
    $('#content').load('http://xxx.com/xxx/get.php');

}
$(window).load(function () {
  onLoad();
});
</script>
```

This way your onLoad function will be loaded when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: Cf. `<input type="button" value="click" onClick="onLoad();">` (but the naming seems a little off :) )

Comment: He/she wants to run the onLoad function when the document is fully loaded if I'm not mistaken, so if you have a button where you set the onClick event to onLoad, you are using the wrong event.

Comment: Yes, the naming suggests that. I was just objecting to the "Your onLoad function is never called" part of your answer. I should read "Your onLoad function is only called when the button is clicked."

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Yes, originally I want the function to load when the document is loaded. but here I just want to call it by onClick. So we can just consider that onLoad here is just a function name. Also, I've tried the solution above. Still don't work. :(

Comment: Yes, jensgram, you're right, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: ShyFaz, then the content of your function is incorrect. Have you tried something like $('#result').load('http://xxx.com/xxx/get.php');? Also, did you doublecheck the URL whether it's correct?

Comment: the full link is : http://www.onepixeltech.com/livetraffic/get.php you guys can check by clicking it. And yes, I've tried creating a new div (div id=result) inside the content div, still doesn't work.

Comment: Please read the documentation from here: http://api.jquery.com/load/, you'll be able to solve your problem after that.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but I've already did that and this is what I've come out with. I've just tested, the code works if I load get.php when it's in the same folder of my project, $('#content').load('get.php');, but once I've move it to the server and change to $('#content').load('http://xxx.com/xxx/get.php'); it failed to work... any ideas on this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't know why does this happening to you.

Comment: hello everyone. this problem is solved! turns out that I'm missing the line < uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"> in android manifest. thank you so much for trying to help me...